# Changing UI of android app without updating from google play

Tags: android, parsing, user-interface, push

I am developing a mobile app and I'd like to update the UI. Texts on buttons and number of checkboxes, etc can change. I am using parse.com as backend.
What is the proper way to update UI in this case?

- Updating the app via google play, every time UI changes?
- Sending push notifications including UI change?

[image: ff]

Comment: You cannot change Java code or resources via GCM or any other sort of push mechanism.

Comment: Can't the app receive the number of checkboxes with a push message, write it to parse local store and in the next run creates checkboxes with something like:                                          `for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {`
         `CheckBox ch = new CheckBox(this);`
         `ch.setText("I'm dynamic!");

            ll.addView(ch);
        }`

Comment: That is certainly possible. However, you are not changing Java code or resources that way, which is why my first comment was about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change ressources or java code from push notifications or any other mechanism than one that recompile the sources in a apk file. So if you built your UI from native android views, you will have to update your app from the google play. However, if you wish to modify your UI dynamically from the server,  you could use webviews (received from the server) as the main content UI of your app.(usually not recommended, depends what you are willing to do).